# Angular 6 Unable to get data from external server API using proxy

Tags: angular, api, proxy

I'm using local angular app and I get problem to get data from API on external server. I tried to use proxy, so I create file **proxyconfig.json** and I included it in command line via

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxyconfig.json
```

And here is content:

```
{
    "/api/*": {
    "target": "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/",
        "secure": false,
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/api": ""
        },
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

I need to pass variables so I created service **OrderBookService**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { OrderBook } from './order-book.model';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
  })
export class OrderBookService {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {

    }
    getOrderBookBittrex(currency1: string, currency2: string): Observable<OrderBook[]> {
        const url = `http://localhost:4200/api/getorderbook?market=${currency1}-${currency2}&type=both`;
        return this.httpClient.get<OrderBook[]>(url);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I want to get this data and save it to variable in my component, path is not translating properly: it's sending request to **http://localhost:4200/api/getorderbook?market=BTC-LTC&type=both** instead of 
**https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getorderbook?market=BTC-LTC&type=both** :

```
  private getTransfers(): void {
    const currency1 = 'BTC';
    const currency2 = 'LTC';
    this.orderBookService.getOrderBookBittrex(currency1, currency2)
      .subscribe(orders => {
        this.orderBook = orders;
      });
  }
```

[image: This is console log]

Anybody knows how to do it properly?

It's working fine when I put all path to proxconfig.json like this:

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getorderbook?market=BTC-LTC&type=both",
        "secure": false,
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/api": ""
        },
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

But I need to pass variables.

Comment: send request to 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getorderbook?market=BTC-LTC&type=both' instead of  'http://localhost:4200/api/getorderbook?market=${currency1}-${currency2}&type=both' what's the confusion here?

Comment: It doesn't work that way for CORS reason: **Failed to load https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public//getorderbook?market=BTC-LTC&type=both: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.**
So I trying to use proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code

```
getOrderBookBittrex(currency1: string, currency2: string): Observable<OrderBook[]> {
    const url = `http://localhost:4200/api/getorderbook?market=${currency1}-${currency2}&type=both`;
    return this.httpClient.get<OrderBook[]>(url);
}
```

Just change url like

```
getOrderBookBittrex(currency1: string, currency2: string): Observable<OrderBook[]> {
    const url = `/api/getorderbook?market=${currency1}-${currency2}&type=both`;
    return this.httpClient.get<OrderBook[]>(url);
}
```

You don't need use http://localhost:4200 in you code.

And `"pathRewrite": {
            "^/api": ""
        },`
don't need too

Comment: Works. Can You tell me how to auto update view from this API server without refreshing page?

Comment: See - Reactive Forms - for Forms, and you can use ngModel for any ouputs

Comment: Example (paginator):
someArray - we put some data from server
getSome(page) = func in service, get data of one page of few
----------------
in .ts file
page:number = 1
someArray:any[]=[]

someChange(page){
this._req.getSome(page).subscribe(
result=>{
this.someArray = result['some_content']
}
)
}

if .html file

<div *ngFor="let elem of someArray ">
{{elem}}
</div>
<nav>
<ul>
<li (click)="someChange(1)">Page 1</li>
<li (click)="someChange(2)">Page 2</li>
</ul>
</nav>